# Time Machine for reformatted external FileVault drive: how to explore files in backups; make future backups incremental from there

Tags: time-machine, high-sierra, external-disk, filevault

After the latest backup of an FileVault-encrypted SD was made on TimeMachine, I *manually* moved the its contents to another disk, then reformatted it, again as encrypted volume, and moved the file contents back to the SD from that disk.

1. How can I browse the contents of that backup to selectively restore some files?

   Currently when I "Enter Time Machine", I get:

   > "The folder 'volume-name' can't be opened because you don't have permissions to see its contents".

   And I don't see "ComputerName > Users > username > username.sparsevolume" when browsing the versions in TimeMachine as [some](https://www.lifewire.com/using-finder-to-access-filevault-backups-time-machine-2260095) [sources](http://www.baligu.com/pondini/TM/25.html) suggest.
2. How can I make the reformatted volume *incrementally* backed up basing on the latest pre-formatting backup TimeMachine stores?

---

I've read [the earlier answer](https://superuser.com/a/1148703/53983) on re-associating the re-formatted volume with its ealier backup. But given it's one-way action [per](https://simon.heimlicher.com/articles/2012/07/10/time-machine-inherit-backup-using-tmutil/), I'd like to ask for second opinion that it's exactly what I need to address both parts of my question:

> The following command [`tmutil associatedisk`] permanently manipulates the association of your Time Machine disk. Use it only once you understand what this means. You proceed at your own risk.

If so, do I need to associate a *single snapshot* or *all snapshots*?

I've never backed up that SD after re-formatting.

MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G65); Macbook Air mid-2011.